# Calling an external command in Go

Tags: go

How can I call an external command in GO?
I need to call an external program and wait for it to finish execution. before the next statement is executed.

Comment: Who voted to close as "not about programming" ?

Comment: Did you even check the official package doc? http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the [exec package](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) : start a command using [Command](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) and use `Run` to wait for completion.

```
cmd := exec.Command("yourcommand", "some", "args")
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil { 
    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}
```

If you just want to read the result, you may use [Output](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output) instead of `Run`.

Answer (score 3):

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os/exec"
  "log"
)

func main() {
  cmd := exec.Command("ls", "-ltr")
  out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("%s\n", out)
}
```

**[Try online](https://code.labstack.com/zxApDsif)**