# How to copy a file from one directory to another using "os/exec" package in GO

Tags: linux, go

if I am in directory A and running the GO code, and I need to copy a file from directory B to directory C , how to do it? I tried adding cmd.Dir = "B" but it can copy the files in "B" directory, but when I try full path for directory "C" it throws error "exit status 1"

basic code sample

Currently in directory A with location "/var/A"
cmd := exec.Command("cp","/var/C/c.txt","/var/B/")
err := cmd.Run()

Comment: https://godoc.org/os/exec

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420685/calling-an-external-command-in-go)

Answer (score 2):

["os/exec"](https://godoc.org/os/exec) is the Go package used to run external programs, which would include Linux utilities.

```
// The command name is the first arg, subsequent args are the
// command arguments.
cmd := exec.Command("tr", "a-z", "A-Z")
// Provide an io.Reader to use as standard input (optional)
cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("some input")
// And a writer for standard output (also optional)
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
// Run the command and wait for it to finish (the are other
// methods that allow you to launch without waiting.
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("in all caps: %q\n", out.String())
```

Comment: thanks!! I have another question, if I am in directory A and running the GO code, and I need to copy a file from directory B to directory C , how do it do it? I tried adding cmd.Dir = "A" it can copy the files back in "A" directory, but when I try full path for directory "C" it throws error "exit status 1". Please help me with this

Comment: `../B`, `../C`? Assuming `x/A`, `x/B`, `x/C`. `..` means "the parent directory".

Comment: directory A = "/var/www/vhosts/api/src/copy.go". directory B = "/mnt/home/sftp" and directory C = "/tmp/nitin". All the above directory resides on the same server.

Comment: `cp /mnt/home/sftp/file.name /tmp/nitin/file.name` If it errors out you need to get the error message from standard error and proceed from there. Maybe figure out how to do it manually from the shell first?

Comment: Manually from the shell the command works, but when I try the same from GO code the standard error it throws is "exit status 1"

Comment: Standard error, as in the IO stream, not the returned error.

Comment: I am new to GO and I am not sure how to get the Standard error from the IO stream by using the "os/exec" package

Comment: When I tried with this approach, I was able to copy the file                       
  ` func Copy(dst, src string) error {
        in, err := os.Open(src)
        if err != nil {
                return err 
        }   
        defer in.Close()
        out, err := os.Create(dst)
        if err != nil {
                return err 
        }   
        defer out.Close()
        _, err = io.Copy(out, in) 
        cerr := out.Close()
        if err != nil {
                return err 
        }   
        return cerr
}`